# I want that the elements of the layergroup are visible in the legend

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new in Javascript and leaflet. I have a map and a I want to have a legend on the map with some images (results) ordered by the belonging dataset.

I want something like:

[image: legend]

As you can see each dataset contains some results. So a dataset is a group of results.

So in my code I did a layer group for each image. All the layer groups of the same dataset are added to another layer group (dataset) and this layer is added to a layer control (legend)

But as a result I have a layer control with Dataset1 and dataset 2.

I know that I should use layer controls to have the name of each result inside the dataset, but i can't add a layer control to a layer group without having an error.

My code with the solution of the layer group is:

head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster-layer-for-leaflet"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/togeojson@0.16.0"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geotiff/leaflet-geotiff.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-filelayer@1.2.0"></script>

</head>
```

Body:

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        // Create a master control for algorithms
        var legendLayerControl = L.control.layers().addTo(map);
        // var testLayerControlDataset = L.control.layers().addTo(map);
        // var testLayerControlMain = L.control.layers().addTo(map);

        function addGeoTIFFToAlgorithm(imagePath, groupName, layeralgorithm) {
            fetch(imagePath)
                .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                .then(arrayBuffer => parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer))
                .then(georaster => {
                    var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                        georaster: georaster,
                        opacity: 0.7,
                        resolution: 256
                    });
                    layer.name = groupName;
                    layerResult = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
                    layerResult.addLayer(layer);

                    layeralgorithm.addLayer(layerResult);

                    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());


                    // testLayerControlDataset.addOverlay(layer, "test");
                    // testLayerControlMain.addLayer(testLayerControlDataset, "Alg"); //Error
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error loading image:', error));
        }

        var imagePath1 = 'Ortomosaico.tif';
        var imagePath2 = 'example_4326.tif';
        var alg1Layer = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
        addGeoTIFFToAlgorithm(imagePath1, "result 1", alg1Layer);
        addGeoTIFFToAlgorithm(imagePath2, "result 1", alg1Layer);

        legendLayerControl.addOverlay(alg1Layer, "Dataset 1");

        var alg2Layer = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
        addGeoTIFFToAlgorithm(imagePath2, "result 2", alg2Layer);
        legendLayerControl.addOverlay(alg2Layer, "Dataset 2");


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What can i do? Thanks in advance!